# How to remove the duplicate data in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

How to remove the duplicate asset?.

***list.component.ts***

```
this.rowData.push(
      { 'code': 'BSA', 'asset': 'PRN', 'assetCount': 1, 'date': '2018-02-01 03:00:00' },
      { 'code': 'BSIT', 'asset': 'PRN', 'assetCount': 2, 'date': '2019-01-01 01:01:00' },
      { 'code': 'BSCS', 'asset': 'PRN2', 'assetCount': 3, 'date': '2019-01-01 00:10:00' },
      { 'code': 'BSBA', 'asset': 'PRN2', 'assetCount': 5, 'date': '2019-01-01 01:00:00' },
      { 'code': 'BSE', 'asset': 'PRN', 'assetCount': 6, 'date': '2019-02-01 00:20:00' },
    );

let valArr = this.rowData.map((item) => {
        return item['asset'];
      });
```

***output***

```
rowData = ["PRN", "PRN2", "PRN2", "PRN"]
```

***expected output***

Duplicate objects should return like below.

```
rowData = ["PRN", "PRN2"]
```

Comment: If you don't bother in filtering your ```valArr``` then you can filter the ```valArr``` like, ```valArr.filter((elem, index, self) => {
    return index === self.indexOf(elem)
})```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [**Set**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) with [**Spread syntax**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to filter the unique values from an array:

```js
var rowData = [
      { 'code': 'BSA', 'asset': 'PRN', 'assetCount': 1, 'date': '2018-02-01 03:00:00' },
      { 'code': 'BSIT', 'asset': 'PRN', 'assetCount': 2, 'date': '2019-01-01 01:01:00' },
      { 'code': 'BSCS', 'asset': 'PRN2', 'assetCount': 3, 'date': '2019-01-01 00:10:00' },
      { 'code': 'BSBA', 'asset': 'PRN2', 'assetCount': 5, 'date': '2019-01-01 01:00:00' },
      { 'code': 'BSE', 'asset': 'PRN', 'assetCount': 6, 'date': '2019-02-01 00:20:00' },
];

let valArr = [...new Set(rowData.map(item => item['asset']))];

console.log(valArr);
```

Comment: Error: ```Type 'Set<{}>' is not an array type or a string type. Use compiler option '--downlevelIteration' to allow iterating of iterators.```

Comment: go to `tsconfig.json` and add in `"downlevelIteration": true"` to `compilerOptions`.  You also probably need to change `"target": "es5"` to es6 also cause `Set` is an ES6 new feature

Comment: done added ```"downlevelIteration": true``` inside the ```compilerOptions``` and also I already the ```es5``` to ```es6```

Answer (score 1):

You can use reduce method to do this.Don't use lodash much.

```
let valArr = rowData.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
   if(accumulator.indexOf(currentValue.asset) === -1)
     accumulator.push(currentValue.asset);
   return accumulator;
},[]);
```

Comment: what is the value of ``acc``?

Comment: acc is actually accumulator. I forgot to change that. Edited now. I hope it is working for you now

Answer (score 1):

For the array manipulation I would suggest please use Loadash as it has various functions to play with Arrays

If you want to use Lodash then install lodash by `npm i lodash`

then impport "uniqBy" by below line in component

```
import uniqBy from  'lodash'

  let uniqDataSet = uniqBy(this.rowData, (data)=>{
        return data["asset"]
    });
```

uniqDataSet will give you unique dataset.

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous ways to achieve this.
1. **Using Array filter method**:

```
let valArr = this.rowData.map((item) => item['asset'])
                 .filter((asset, index, selfArray) => selfArray.indexOf(asset) === index);
```

2. **Using JSON or Map**: 
    A. Store the item['asset'] in the json instead of array.

```js
    let myJson = {};  
     this.rowData.forEach(item => myJson[item['asset']] = item // put any thing you want sincce you only care abouot the keys.)  
    /** Now if yo want those keys in array format only, 
     *   then you can convert them to array.  **/
     let finalArray = Object.keys(myJson);
```

3. **Using Sets**: Look at Mamun's answer

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```js
var rowData = [
    { 'code': 'BSA', 'asset': 'PRN', 'assetCount': 1, 'date': '2018-02-01 03:00:00' },
    { 'code': 'BSIT', 'asset': 'PRN', 'assetCount': 2, 'date': '2019-01-01 01:01:00' },
    { 'code': 'BSCS', 'asset': 'PRN2', 'assetCount': 3, 'date': '2019-01-01 00:10:00' },
    { 'code': 'BSBA', 'asset': 'PRN2', 'assetCount': 5, 'date': '2019-01-01 01:00:00' },
    { 'code': 'BSE', 'asset': 'PRN', 'assetCount': 6, 'date': '2019-02-01 00:20:00' },
];

let seenItBefore = {};
let duplicates = [];

rowData.forEach(({ asset }) => {
    if (seenItBefore[asset] && !duplicates.includes(asset)) {
        duplicates.push(asset);
    }
    
    seenItBefore[asset] = true;
});

console.log(duplicates);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var rowData = [
    { 'code': 'BSA', 'asset': 'PRN', 'assetCount': 1, 'date': '2018-02-01 03:00:00' },
    { 'code': 'BSIT', 'asset': 'PRN', 'assetCount': 2, 'date': '2019-01-01 01:01:00' },
    { 'code': 'BSCS', 'asset': 'PRN2', 'assetCount': 3, 'date': '2019-01-01 00:10:00' },
    { 'code': 'BSBA', 'asset': 'PRN2', 'assetCount': 5, 'date': '2019-01-01 01:00:00' },
    { 'code': 'BSE', 'asset': 'PRN', 'assetCount': 6, 'date': '2019-02-01 00:20:00' },
];

let unique = [];

rowData.forEach(row => {
  if (unique.indexOf(row.asset) === -1) {
    unique.push(row.asset);
  }
});

console.log(unique);
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cmvuzt)